# Is there any better way to do like history.back() in django backend?

Tags: javascript, html, django, backend

In Django, I have "form view(GET)" and "action view(POST)"

If there is a validation error or any other error in action view,
I want browser to go back to the previous form page **with the input data wrote by the user remains**.

**I tried:**
At first, I used `return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))`.
This code goes back to the previous page well, **but all the input fields became empty.**

And now I am using `return HttpResponse("<script>history.back();</script>")` this code.
This works very well. but It looks weird sending javascript response.

What I expected was like `return redirect.back()`*(with like HTTP 301 or 30X status code)*

**I was wondering if there is any better way or a proper way like officially provided by Django**.

Comment: Disclaimer - I am not familiar with Django, so my suggestion may not apply to your case. Why don't you validate user input remotely (server-side), return a response indicating if anything was wrong (perhaps highlight the inputs which were invalid), and keep the user on the same page? You would only move to the next step if the server responded that everything is alright.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Oh thanks. I think your suggestion is better for application completeness and UX. However, I prefer form submission method when I aim more for productivity in development in Django(because I can code without javascript in this method) :)  I will think about using it next time. Thanks (I'm not sure if my English grammar is correct)